# Run CPLEX mod within in R script

Tags: r, excel, cplex

I the following setup.
I implemented a model in Rstudio. This model creates data for CPLEX optimization studio. At the moment R creates an excel sheet. This excel sheet in then read by CPLEX into a .dat file. This .dat file in then used in the .mod file in CPLEX. The problem is that at the moment the manual effort is too high, because I have to first run the R file, then switch to the CPLEX file and run this again.

Is there any option to integrate the CPLEX mod into the R model so that with running the R model both the R model and the CPLEX model work?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)  How to call [CPLEX from R](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/doopl-R-sample) ?

In R you can call OPL through a system call:

```
system("oplrun diet.mod diet.dat")
```

But you can also use [RCplex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/index.html) or [cplexAPI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/index.html)